# How to arrange notification above modal antd v5

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using antd version 5 and I face this issue [view here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnPKd.png). Here is my code:

```
<>
      {contextHolder}
      <StyledUsersModal
        open={isChangePasswordUsers}
        onOk={onChangePassword}
        footer={false}
        onCancel={handleChangePasswordUsersClose}
        title={messages['common.changePassword']}
      >
        <ChangePasswordForm
          selectUsers={selectUsers}
          onChangePassword={onChangePassword}
          handleChangePasswordUsersClose={handleChangePasswordUsersClose}
          openNotification={openNotification}
        />
      </StyledUsersModal>
    </>
```

I wanna place notification above the modal.

Comment: I think that you can try to z-index property for your modal

Comment: I tried zIndex={-1} but nothing changes

Comment: Antd Modal have zIndex of 1000. Set notification to `zIndex: 1000` or more. This will notification above the modal

Answer (score 0):

1. The default z-index of Ant's modal is at 1000.
2. You can make z-index of your messageAPI popping up at 1001 by config it at your theme setting, i.e. the Antd's ConfigProvider.
3. For example in my code, I have to make it display above MUI's AppBar. So it will be like this

   <ConfigProvider

   ```
   theme={{
     token: {
       colorPrimary: '#E0282E',
       fontFamily: 'Noto Sans Thai',
     },
     components: {
       Message: {
         zIndexPopupBase: themeV5.zIndex.appBar + 1,
       },
     },
   }}>{...yourChildren}</ConfigProvider>
   ```

> PS: The themeV5.zIndex.appBar comes from the default setting of MUI's
> theme. You can replace it with 1000 or somethings alike.